# Div element should show up when clicked

Tags: javascript, html, css, function

I want a `div` element, on which I click. Then another `div` element should pop up.
I tried something, but don't know, why it doesn't work.

```html
<div class="div" onclick="myFunction()">
  <img class="image" src="..." height="80px" width="80px">
  <h2 class="header">text</h2>
  <img class="more" src="..." height="50px" width="50px">
  </div>
  <script>
  function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById('text')
  [0].classList.toggle('display')
  <div class="news" onclick="myFunction()">
  <img class="coronanewsimg" src="https://www.mediothek-krefeld.de/files/content-fotos/Bilder%20fuer%20Neuigkeiten%20und%20Slider/628px-Achtung.svg.png" height="80px" width="80px">
  <h2 class="coronanewshead">Sonderschließzeit bis vorraussichtlich 07.03.21 aufgrund des Coronavirus</h2>
  <img class="mehr-pfeil" src="pics/mehr-pfeil.png" height="50px" width="50px">
  </div>
  <script>
  function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById('coronanewstext')
  [0].classList.toggle('display')
  }
  </script>
  <div class="text">
text
</div>
```

Comment: you don't seem to have closed your top function or script tag

Comment: Theres are many things that are erroring out...First MyFunction is not define...meaning you getElementById('coronanewstext') doesnt exist. you are looking for an ID but your whole code only has Classes. Another thing is you are looking for `coronanewstext` id which doesn't exist anywhere in your code.

Comment: you should start with a simpler example. your div is class "Text" not ID

Answer (score 1):

You could also use this method to create a `div` element when the event occurs.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Event handling</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <p>Click the button to pop up another div element.</p>
  <button onclick="popDiv()">Click me</button>
 <script>
  function popDiv() {
  var division = document.createElement("div");
  division.innerText = "This is a new DIV element";
  division.style.color = "blue";
  division.style.margin = "10px";           //Simple styling of div
  division.style.background = "whitesmoke";
  division.style.border = "1px solid black";
  document.body.appendChild(division);
  }
 </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Also correct upon the tag's opening and closing in your code, or this may also result in error.

Answer (score 0):

simple example how on click works for an element id

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function displayDate()
{
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=Date();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>How to display the Day, Date, Time at the touch of a button</h1>
<p id="demo">We would like it to appear hear.</p>
<button type="button" onclick="displayDate()">Display Date</button>
</body>
</html>
```